# How to filter by month in sql

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, filter

How to optimize my code using sql queries

```
$collection->filter(function ($item) use ($i) {
  return $item->created_at->month == $i->month;
})->count();
```

I want instead of filter function on a collection to filter in sql so it can be quicker

here is the function :

```
$data = [];
    switch ($range) {
        //monthly
        case self::$timeRanges[0]:
            for ($i = Carbon::now()->copy()->subYear()->endOfMonth(); $i <= Carbon::now()->subMonth()->endOfMonth(); $i->addMonths(1)) {
                $data[$i->month] = $collection->filter(function ($item) use ($i) {
                    return $item->created_at->month == $i->month;
                })->count();
            }
            break;
        //weekly
        case self::$timeRanges[1]:
            $collection = $collection->where('created_at', '>=', Carbon::now()->subWeek()->endOfWeek()->subWeeks(5))->where('created_at', '<=', Carbon::now()->subWeek()->endOfWeek());
            for ($i = Carbon::now()->copy()->subWeek()->endOfWeek()->subWeeks(5); $i <= Carbon::now()->copy()->subWeek()->endOfWeek(); $i->addWeeks(1)) {
                $data[$i->weekOfMonth] = $collection->filter(function ($item) use ($i) {
                    return $item->created_at->weekOfYear == $i->weekOfYear;
                })->count();
            }
            break;
    }
    return ($data);
```

thanks for helping, and have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

Just to extend of @Elie's answer, you don't even need to use a raw query. Laravel beautifully caters for date conditions and it is very well documented on the [Queries](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries) page.

```
$desiredMonth = 12;

Model::whereMonth('created_at', $desiredMonth)->get();
```

However, this does not quite answer the question at hand. What we need to do is retrieve all relevant results and then filter by month on the retrieved results. I believe it will be much more efficient and faster to do this by retrieving all results from SQL and then filtering on them as you are, but with less iterative code:

```
$collection = Model::whereYear(2018)->get();

$months = $collection->groupBy(function ($item, $key) {
    return $item->created_at->month;
});

$months->toArray();

[
    '1' => [[...],[...],[...]],
    '2' => [[...],[...],[...]],
    '3' => [[...],[...],[...]],
    '4' => [[...],[...],[...]],
    '5' => [[...],[...],[...]],
    '6' => [[...],[...],[...]],
    '7' => [[...],[...],[...]],
    '8' => [[...],[...],[...]],
    '9' => [[...],[...],[...]],
    '10' => [[...],[...],[...]],
    '11' => [[...],[...],[...]],
    '12' => [[...],[...],[...]],
]
```

Additionally if you insist on using SQL to do the filtering, you could do a `groupBy`:

```
Model::groupBy(\DB::raw('MONTH(created_at) as month'))->get();
```

You'll need to do your own testing as to which is faster or at least most efficient. Also some databases do not allow multiple groupings (which we don't have here, but you might want to add) without modifying their config so my personal first prize would be the original approach unless you're working with an enormous data set.

Comment: no, now i have it filtered by month on a collection and it's working but it's kind of slow so I thought if I will use a sql query instead it's gonna be quicker

Comment: I've misread your question. Will update my answer shortly, but I'm not sure SQL will be faster in this case, that would be quite a complex query right off the bat - which I'm not even sure how to do myself at first glance.

Comment: @SergiuLeu Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
Model::where(\DB::raw('MONTH(created_at)') , $month )->get();
```

Comment: Type error: Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Support\Collection::where(), 1 passed in /var/www/vinyt-api/app/Services/DashboardFilter.php on line 132 and at least 2 expected
i got this error, but i got your idea thanks

Comment: Fixed, try it now